# Cognos reports - Static choice in value prompt

Tags: static, prompt, cognos

I have a Column 'Status' which has values like Rework, Draft,Cancelled, Reviewed,Completed.
So in the prompt page i want a static choice with display value 'Treated' and 'Not treated'.
When the user selects 'Treated' then the "use values" should be 'Reviewed','Completed'
else if the user selects 'Not treated' it should be 'Rework',' Draft','Cancelled'. So how can we give multiple use values in static choice?

Please help!!!!

Comment: If those aren't in a table, I think you would have to have two separate prompts, one for each set.  If you can use separate prompt pages you can probably use a render variable.  If you want it on the same page, I think you'll want to use JavaScript to show (un-hide) the appropriate second prompt.

Comment: Hi Andrew,I want value prompt which should have 2 values i.e. 'Treated 'and 'Not treated'. If the user clicks on treated and clicks on submit , the report should only display the values 'Reviewed','Completed' in the 'Status' column.

Answer (score 4):

You need to create more advanced filter.

```
(?Selector? = 'Treated' and [Your column] in ('Reviewed','Completed'))
or
(?Selector? = 'Not treated' and [Your column] in ('Rework',' Draft','Cancelled'))
```

Where ?Selector? - you prompt variable.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, you need an if/then in your filter:

```
if (?Prompt? = 'Treated') 
        then ([column] in ('Reviewed','Completed'))
else 
        ([column] in ('Rework','Draft','Cancelled'))
```

The `OR` suggestion below will work as well, I just personally find the if/then logic easier to read.

Comment: The if/then you propose will work and so will the compound booleans of the other answer. There is some evidence that using simply booleans will be slightly more efficient than if/then but I haven't done the performance testing.

Comment: I **think** that with the if then, Cognos will only generate sql with the result of that test. So if the user picked Treated, then the where clause will read `[column] in ('Reviewed','Completed')`. No if/thens, ors, or cases would be sent to the database. I'm not sure what SQL Cognos would generated with the or clause.

Comment: The difference is what is sent to the DB server. In the case if/then, only a where clause equivalent of the selected filter clause will be sent to the DB. In the case of and/or logic, the entire logic structure will be sent as part of the where clause of the SQL statement. Often times DB servers are many times more powerful than Cognos dispatchers and can more efficiently deal with the logic via their query plan. In other words, using and/or takes Cognos out of the decision-making process which is almost always a good thing. That's the theory anyway.